# Get a list of successfully uploaded files from vue-uploader

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How would I be able to get an array of files that were successfully uploaded using this vue-uploader component?

https://github.com/simple-uploader/vue-uploader

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
<template>
  <uploader :options="options">

    <uploader-unsupport></uploader-unsupport>

    <uploader-drop>
      <uploader-btn>Select files to upload...</uploader-btn>
    </uploader-drop>

    <uploader-list @successfully-uploaded-files="mySuccessfullyUploadedFiles"></uploader-list>

  </uploader>

  <pre>{{mySuccessfullyUploadedFiles}}</pre>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        mySuccessfullyUploadedFiles: [],
        options: {
          // https://github.com/simple-uploader/Uploader/tree/develop/samples/Node.js
          target: '//localhost:3000/upload',
          testChunks: false
        },
        attrs: {
          accept: 'image/*'
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I can get a list of files by adding `@file-added` event to the `<uploader>` element but it doesn't include the status of the file so that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
<template>
  <uploader :options="options" @file-success="mySuccessfullyUploadedFiles.push($event)">

    <uploader-unsupport></uploader-unsupport>

    <uploader-drop>
      <uploader-btn>Select files to upload...</uploader-btn>
    </uploader-drop>

    <uploader-list></uploader-list>

  </uploader>

  <pre>{{mySuccessfullyUploadedFiles}}</pre>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        mySuccessfullyUploadedFiles: [],
        options: {
          // https://github.com/simple-uploader/Uploader/tree/develop/samples/Node.js
          target: '//localhost:3000/upload',
          testChunks: false
        },
        attrs: {
          accept: 'image/*'
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```